# How to change columns, drop inverted commas and add tabulation to a text file with bash

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, awk, text

I'm quite new into bash and awk in bash scripting and from this text that I have in a file:

```
"Index", "Year", "Age", "Name", "Movie"
1, 1928, 44, "Emil Jannings", "The Last Command, The Way of All Flesh" 
2, 1929, 41, "Warner Baxter", "In Old Arizona"
3, 1930, 62, "George Arliss", "Disraeli"
4, 1931, 53, "Lionel Barrymore", "A Free Soul"
```

I need to create a function to have this output, sorting by the name of the actor, changing some of the heading names and including tabulation.

```
Actor               Year    Age   Film
Emil Jannings       1928    44    The Last Command, The Way of All Flesh
George Arliss       1930    62    Disraeli
Lionel Barrymore    1931    53    A Free Soul
Warner Baxter       1929    41    In Old Arizona
```

How would you do it? I'm still a beginner and I can't find the correct way to have what I want.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Text files can't have headings "in bold".  If you need that, you need some kind of document, eg. html.  Any idea?  What would be displaying this document?

Comment: I'd recommend using a language that comes with a proper CSV parser (python, ruby, ...) or a specialized package like [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.1/index.html)

Comment: I'm trying with commands like sort, cut, paste, using echo to write the headings, etc. but I'm stuck. For example, how would you drop the inverted commas and tabulate? I also feel like I'm making it harder than it is. 

The headings in bold aren't necessary actually, so I can skip that part.
This was just an exercise I need to solve in bash...

Comment: Parsing CSV is tricky, as you see with the embedded comma. You don't need to reinvent that wheel. Use a proper tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

With `csvcut` from the python-based csvkit and Miller:

```
$ csvcut -S -c Name,Year,Age,Movie file.csv | 
     mlr --icsv --opprint sort -f Name then rename Name,Actor,Movie,Film
Actor            Year Age Film
Emil Jannings    1928 44  The Last Command, The Way of All Flesh
George Arliss    1930 62  Disraeli
Lionel Barrymore 1931 53  A Free Soul
Warner Baxter    1929 41  In Old Arizona
```

Although I think Miller should be able to do this on its own, it seems to mis-parse the quoted delimiter when it is not a single character.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    in2outTag["Name"]  = "Actor"
    in2outTag["Movie"] = "Film"
    numOutFlds = split("Actor Year Age Film",outTags)
    FPAT = "\\s*(([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\"))\\s*"
    OFS = "\t"
}

{
    for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]*"?|"?[[:space:]]*$/,"",$inFldNr)
    }
}

NR == 1 {
    for (inFldNr=1; inFldNr<=NF; inFldNr++) {
        tag = ( $inFldNr in in2outTag ? in2outTag[$inFldNr] : $inFldNr )
        tag2inNr[tag] = inFldNr
    }

    printf "%d%s", 0, OFS
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        tag = outTags[outFldNr]
        out2inNr[outFldNr] = tag2inNr[tag]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (outFldNr < numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    next
}

{
    printf "%d%s", 1, OFS
    for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
        inFldNr = out2inNr[outFldNr]
        val = $inFldNr
        printf "%s%s", val, (outFldNr < numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1n -k2,2 | cut -f2-
Actor   Year    Age     Film
Emil Jannings   1928    44      The Last Command, The Way of All Flesh
George Arliss   1930    62      Disraeli
Lionel Barrymore        1931    53      A Free Soul
Warner Baxter   1929    41      In Old Arizona
```